# Another flutter_svg.dart error. Unable to load asset

Tags: android, flutter, svg

This question has been asked a LOT!!!  I have gone through all the recommendations which I will be listing below but still no go.  Need help.

=======
Problem:  SVG files won't load using Flutter package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart.

=======
Config Snippet:

final String myimage1str = 'images/splashtest.svg';
final Widget myimage1 = SvgPicture.asset('myimage1str',semanticsLabel: 'Wazzup!!',color: Colors.blue,);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
body: Center(
child: Stack(
children: [
Container(
//child: SvgPicture.asset("images/splashtest.svg",height: 900.0,width: 540.0,allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,),
child:  myimage1
),

=======
Error:

Unable to load asset: myimage1str

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)

=======
Tshoot steps already taken:

1. Check syntax/position/spacing in pubspec.yaml.

[image]

2. Images folder is located under root.

[image]

3. Ran flutter clean.
4. Invalidated caches and restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using websafe_svg instead. It's a lot better and simplier, here is an example of some code.

```
WebsafeSvg.asset(
    'dev_assets/cfg67.svg',
    color: Colors.red,
    height: 25,
    width: 25,
),
```

Package Link: [Websafe SVG Package](https://pub.dev/packages/websafe_svg)